# OTL 4.0 in code::Block

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Recently I decided to move to open source, so I stumbled into `Code::Block` which has a nice GUI, `(WXwidgets)`. I am dealing a lot with databases like MS Access and SQLite. Having burned some midnight oil trying to figure out how to use `OTL 4.0`, I gave up!

I'm able to include the header file like this in cpp `(wxFrame)`

```c++
#define OTL_ODBC // Compile OTL 4.0/ODBC
#include <otlv4.h> // include the OTL 4.0 header file
```

The Auto Complete in this code block did not show the `otl_connect` object:

```
otl_connect db; // connect object
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't that be #define and #include ?

Comment: Yes, Sorry the # were there in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should include **all** the `#define`s posted in the OTL examples, otherwise they don't work.